# Not able to access image from xcassets

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, frameworks

I am creating **.framework** and **.bundle** of my application.
Then i am importing **.framework** and **.bundle** into my demo application.

In demo application i am launching another application using .framework.
But in that i am not able to see images.

Code in framework as follow:

```
[ratingImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_rating_half_star"]];+
```

The images which are set using storyboard are displaying, but only images which are set using programmatically are not displaying as above.